# Cannot login to ubuntu as original user anylonger

Tags: authentication

I have created an ubuntu VM with "vagrant" user and (ssh) public-key authentication. Then I have created a new user "sshuser" changing the configuration file:

`etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the lines:

`PasswordAuthentication yes` and `AllowUsers sshuser`

Now I am not able to login with "vagrant" user anymore since it asks for password but that user is authenticated via key.

```
login as: vagrant
Server refused our key
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
```

Also, I do not know if and how I can switch to "root".

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from manpage for sshd_config file.

> AllowUsers
>                This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns,
>                separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed **only** for
>                user names that match one of the patterns.

User vagrant is not specified in your AllowUsers directive, therefore he can`t login. You should add username vagrant in your AllowUsers directive preceded by a space.

> AllowUsers sshuser vagrant